# How serialized header block is divided?

Tags: http2

I'm implementing my own HTTP/2 server. Read through the RFC 7540, a portion of content about HTTP header frame got me confused:

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.3
>
> Header lists are collections of zero or more header fields.  When
> transmitted over a connection, a header list is serialized into a
> header block using HTTP header compression [COMPRESSION].  The
> serialized header block is then divided into one or more octet
> sequences, called header block fragments

So in my imagination, the process would look like:

```
+-------------------+    +-------------------+    +------------------+    +---------+
|    Header List    |    |    Header Block   |    | Block Fragment 1 | -> | Frame 1 | 
+-------------------+    +-------------------+    +------------------+    +---------+
| :method = POST    |    | Header 1 Bin Data |    | Block Fragment 2 | -> | Frame 2 |
| :path = /resource | -> | Header 2 Bin Data | -> +------------------+    +---------+ 
| :scheme = https   |    | Header 3 Bin Data |    | Block Fragment 3 | -> | Frame 3 |
| .....             |    | Header 4 Bin ...  |    +------------------+    +---------+
+-------------------+    +-------------------+    ...                     ...
```

But how the serialized header block got divided does not mentioned in the section.

So my question is: **Is that possible to separate/divide one HTTP header into multiple Header Block Fragments?** For example, part of *Header 1 Bin Data* is carried by *Block Fragment 1*, and the rest is carried by *Block Fragment 2*.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to split the bytes corresponding to 1 HTTP header into 2 (or more) frames.

You encode the HTTP headers into bytes via HPACK, so you have now just a `byte[]`.
Let's assume the `byte[]` has length 23.

You can create a `HEADERS` frame with flags `end_headers=false` and put for example 13 of the 23 bytes into it.
Then, you create a `CONTINUATION` frame with flags `end_headers=true` and put the remaining 10 bytes into it.

It is completely opaque where you split the `byte[]`.

The important thing is that the `HEADERS` and `CONTINUATION` frames must be sent one after the other, with no other frame between them.

The receiving side will see the `HEADERS` frame with `end_headers=false`, will extract the 13 bytes and will put them aside, waiting for a `CONTINUATION` frame.
When the `CONTINUATION` frame arrives, the receiving side will extract the 10 bytes, concatenate it with the previous 13 to obtain a copy of the original 23 bytes that can now be decoded via HPACK, obtaining the original HTTP headers.

Comment: This answer is correct. However there are sever limitations on it. The CONTINUATION frame must immediately follow the preceding HEADERS/CONTINUATION/PUSH_PROMISE frame (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-6.10). This means the HTTP/2 connection is held up (HOL blocked) and cannot process other streams. Really, really, really large header blocks that cannot fit into the SETTINGS_MAX_FRAME_SIZE are probably the main reason to use it and they should be rare. For this reason it is little used and it would not surprise me if some implementations were buggy or even didn't support it at all.